# Running batch command inside script to start SimpleHTTPServer not working properly

Tags: python, batch-file, simplehttpserver

I'm trying to start `SIMPLEHTTPSERVER` from inside python via an `os.system` batch command to serve to a specific directory.

In a regular batch file, I have:

```batch
@echo off
pushd c:\MC\log
start C:\Python27\python.exe -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

Which works great, but in Python if I use:

```
os.system('cmd /c pushd c:\MC\log start C:\Python27\python.exe -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080')
```

it starts the server, but seems to ignore the server directory.

Is it clear where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You may be interested in the `subprocess` module - its [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) function allows you to set the working directory. Alternatively you could try [os.chdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) to temporarily change cwd from within python.

Comment: os.chdir did the trick.  Thank you!  os.chdir("c:\MC\log")
os.system('cmd /c C:\Python27\python.exe -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080')

Comment: You need to add some separation between your `pushd` and `start` commands. You can use a double-ampersand `&&` to chain commands on successful operation.

Comment: `pushd` is actually not needed, use `start`'s `/D` option: `start "" /D "C:\MC\log" "C:\Python27\python.exe" -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`